# Finding value of int x

Tags: c++, int

```
int x;
x=x+30;
cout << x;
```

the output will be 33, why is it so?
 I didn't even declare x as 3.
Can someone guides me? Thanks!

Comment: does that not produce warnings when compiled? Because it bloodly well should!

Comment: nope, it gives me a value of 33.

Comment: compile EVERYTHING with -Wall

Comment: Use `-Wall` and  `warning: 'x' is used uninitialized in this function`

Comment: @user2611244 - Compile your code with all warnings enabled. Quite easy to configure (NB: VS defaults to level 3, go to the properties page for the project to set it to all)

Comment: @MitchWheat - Why or why does a compiler not default to '-Wall'? I think we should be told

Comment: Your code has a bug. Fix the bug and the mystery will go away.

Comment: @EdHeal here's the proof:http://i1146.photobucket.com/albums/o530/HTHVampire/C%20plus%20plus/Capture_zps562bb419.png

Comment: You haven't initialized x. So the value 3 is a garbage value. If you run the code again (after refreshing the heap), you will most probably get a different value.

Comment: @user2611244 - Try again with `g++ -Wall` instead.

Comment: @EdHeal It gives me an error finally, what command is that?

Comment: @user2611244 - It is g++ (as you originally used) but with an option. See http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++ for this and other optional delights

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior. You got 33 due to an unreliable sequence of implementation quirks. The program is free to produce any value at all, fail to compile, or hire an assassin to stab you.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, variables are given space (memory allocation) by default equal to the size of the variable, but they are not given values by default.